# Location not updated on 10 mins of interval

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-gps

I want to track the user location. So I have made a code so that on every 10 mins of interval its location should be hit on server. If it is not moving also the location should hit at 10 min of interval. I set Location interval minutes for 10 min                                                   public static final long LOCATION_INTERVAL_MINUTES = 10 * 60 * 1000;
It should update the location with 10 min, but  it hits randomly. I also increase the gps frequency distance from 10 to  gpsFreqInDistance = 100 .Random hits are stopped but it will not updated on 10 mins of interval.
So what to do to get location at 10 min of interval.
Below is my manifiest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />      

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" /
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

As for Android above 10version u cant use background location and foreground location simultaneously. So i comment the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" in my project.

```
 public class LocationMonitoringService implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {


    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    private LocationRepository mLocationRepository;

    private ShareLocationAdapterClass mAdapter;

    private SyncOfflineRepository syncOfflineRepository;

    private long updatedTime = 0;

    private List<UserLocationPojo> mUserLocationPojoList;

    private SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository syncOfflineAttendanceRepository;


    public LocationMonitoringService(final Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        mLocationRepository = new LocationRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineRepository = new SyncOfflineRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository = new SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        mUserLocationPojoList = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new ShareLocationAdapterClass();

        mAdapter.setShareLocationListener(new ShareLocationAdapterClass.ShareLocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccessCallBack(boolean isAttendanceOff) {
                if (isAttendanceOff && !syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkIsAttendanceIn()) {
                    AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                    ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailureCallBack() {

            }
        });
    }

    public void onStartTacking() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Exception thrown when GPS or Network provider were not available on the user's device.
        try {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

            //API level 9 and up
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);



            int gpsFreqInDistance = 100;

            assert locationManager != null;
            locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this, null);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this, null);



        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void onStopTracking() {
        mAdapter.shareLocation();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */


    //to get the location change
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("okh ", "onLocationChanged:   "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (location != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));

            if (!AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())) && !AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()))) {

                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LAT, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LONG, String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

                if (Prefs.getBoolean(AUtils.PREFS.IS_ON_DUTY, false)) {
                    if (updatedTime == 0) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);
                    }

                    if ((updatedTime + AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL_MINUTES) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);
                    }

                    sendLocation();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:  no location found !!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged" + provider + "Status" + status);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderEnabled" + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderDisabled" + provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

    }

    private void sendLocation() {

        //  mAdapter.shareLocation(getTempList());
        Log.d("okh", "sendLocation: Current Time In Millies "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

        try {
            Calendar CurrentTime = AUtils.getCurrentTime();
            Calendar DutyOffTime = AUtils.getDutyEndTime();

            if (CurrentTime.before(DutyOffTime)) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Before");

                UserLocationPojo userLocationPojo = new UserLocationPojo();

                userLocationPojo.setUserId(Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_ID, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLat(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLong(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, ""));
                double startLat = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, "0"));
                double startLng = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, "0"));
                userLocationPojo.setDistance(String.valueOf(AUtils.calculateDistance(
                        AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext(), startLat, startLng)));
//                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTime()); //TODO
                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTimeLocal());
                userLocationPojo.setOfflineId("0");

                if (AUtils.isInternetAvailable() && AUtils.isConnectedFast(mContext))
                    userLocationPojo.setIsOffline(true);
                else
                    userLocationPojo.setIsOffline(false);

                String UserTypeId = Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_TYPE_ID, AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI);
                if (AUtils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                    TableDataCountPojo.LocationCollectionCount count = syncOfflineRepository.getLocationCollectionCount(AUtils.getLocalDate());
                    if ((UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI) || UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_WASTE_MANAGER))
                            && (count.getLocationCount() > 0 || count.getCollectionCount() > 0)) {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    } else {
                        mUserLocationPojoList.add(userLocationPojo);
                        mAdapter.shareLocation(mUserLocationPojoList);
                        mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_EMP_SCANNIFY)) {
                        Type type = new TypeToken<UserLocationPojo>() {
                        }.getType();
                        mLocationRepository.insertUserLocationEntity(new Gson().toJson(userLocationPojo, type));
                    } else {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    }
                    mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "After");

                syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.performCollectionInsert(mContext,
                        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkAttendance(), AUtils.getCurrentDateDutyOffTime());

                AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();

                Activity activity = ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant);

                if (activity instanceof DashboardActivity) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                    AUtils.DutyOffFromService = true;
                }

                if (!AUtils.isNull(AUtils.currentContextConstant)) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Below is the foreground service which i have used

```
public class ForgroundService extends Service {

    private LocationMonitoringService monitoringService;

    private Handler locationHandler;

    private Runnable locationThread;

   

     @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
//        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("okh", "onCreate: " +System.currentTimeMillis());
        monitoringService = new LocationMonitoringService(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

//        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("okh", "onCreate: " +System.currentTimeMillis());

        Log.d("okh", "onStartCommand: ");
        final int currentId = startId;

        locationThread = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                monitoringService.onStartTacking();
            }
        };

        locationHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        locationHandler.post(locationThread);

        startLocationForeground();

        return Service.START_STICKY;

//        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        locationHandler.removeCallbacks(locationThread);
        monitoringService.onStopTracking();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);
        }

        if(Prefs.getBoolean(AUtils.PREFS.IS_ON_DUTY,false))
        {
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, RestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }

    private void startLocationForeground() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                    ? this.createNotificationChannel("my_service", "My Background Service")
                    : "";

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder((Context) this,
                    channelId);


            Notification notification = notificationBuilder
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentText("Please don't kill the app from background. Thank you!!")
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder))
                    .setPriority(-2)
                    .setCategory("service")
                    .build();

            startForeground(101, notification);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(26)
    private String createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName) {

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId, (CharSequence)channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);

        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager service = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        service.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        return channelId;
    }

    private int getNotificationIcon(NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int color = 0x008000;
            notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
            return R.drawable.ic_noti_icon;

        }
        return R.drawable.ic_noti_icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: From Where you are calling this method? Are you passing the Application context or Activity context?

Comment: @Arunachalamk- I am passing Application context

Answer (score 0):

Why you are passing null in the last parameter? Did you try without passing that?

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                gpsFreqInDistance, this, null);
```

First of all Google Location Services are far better than Traditional LocationManager to achieve this requirement.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

Comment: @Arunachalam-No i didnt try.Do u think that this will work for me.

Comment: @gopssays Please share the code snippet you have used for Google Location Services

Comment: I am  using LocationManager not google location services